# react-native-permissions - iOS - requestNotifications()

Tags: react-native, react-native-permissions

What is the right way to use the "requestNotifications" function? Defined in the library "react-native-permissions".

I tried:

```
await requestNotifications({
            sound: true,
            vibrate: true,
            alert: true,
        });
```

but i get the error "... if type NSMutableDisctionary cannot be converted to NSArray"

What is wrong with the function call?

Function declare is `requestNotifications(options: NotificationOption[]): Promise<NotificationsResponse>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function require arrays with string instead of object.
So your code should looks like
`requestNotifications(['alert', 'sound'])`

Possible options:
'alert'
| 'badge'
| 'sound'
| 'criticalAlert'
| 'carPlay'
| 'provisional'
| 'providesAppSettings';

[More informations](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions#requestnotifications)